# how to modify an item's value in a SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Supposing I have this sqlite database structure:

```
 ID     PRODUCT_NAME     AVAILABILITY 

  1       foo            0
  2       bar            1
  3       baz            0
  4       faz            1
```

How cand I modify the value of the `AVAILABILITY` fom 1 -> 0 where `PRODUCT_NAME = 'bar'` ?
Something like this,
Pseudocod:

```
db.execSQL( "UPDATE TABLE" + Table_name + "MODIFY" + availability + "=" + 0 + "WHERE" +  product_name + "like ? " + 'bar');
```

I assume that I also have to drop and recreate table using onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods, right?
Some code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the example below.  To change an existing row, use "update".  To add a new row, use "insert".  To check for equality, use "`availability like 'bar'`" or "`availability = 'bar'`".  In either case, you need single quotes around "bar".

Comment: I'm trying these hints wright now....

Comment: "I assume that I also have to drop and recreate table using onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods, right?" - No, these methods are used only when your database version changes, to completely recreate your tables - if the structure doesn't change (column or table names, new columns, etc.), the update query is enough

Comment: @AlexB:  your prob solved or not?

Comment: Thanks guys, all of you have provided me some excellent solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
String sql="update "+Table_name+" set availability='0' where product_name like 'bar'";
Object[] bindArgs={"bar"};
try{
            db.execSQL(sql, bindArgs);
return true;
}catch(SQLException ex){
Log.d(tag,"update data failure");
return false;
}
```

Comment: `product_name like ?` if you put the `"bar"` in bindArgs

Comment: Yes, I have solved it finally using your code and @zapl's hint, his code is also great. I got late because I was doing an error in my code: I update the table, then I reinsert data somewhere, and I couldn't see the update...

Answer (score 2):

You want `update` not `alter`. `alter` is for the database schema, `update` is for the data stored in it.

For example:
`update TABLE_NAME set AVAILABILITY = 0 where PRODUCT_NAME like 'bar';`

Also, **do not** just stick strings together to build an sql query. Use a prepared statement or other statement building library to avoid SQL injection attacks and errors.

Comment: Ok, I have modified the question,from `ALTER` to `UPDTAE` but I'm still not able to write the correct SQL command.

Comment: Did you put spaces in the right places? Looks like not from the above.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `update()`, `insert()`, `query()`, `delete()` methods that Android gives you

```java
// define the new value you want
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("AVAILABILITY", 0);
// you can .put() even more here if you want to update more than 1 row

// define the WHERE clause w/o the WHERE and replace variables by ?
// Note: there are no ' ' around ? - they are added automatically
String whereClause = "PRODUCT_NAME == ?";

// now define what those ? should be
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
        // in order the ? appear
        "bar"
};

int amountOfUpdatedColumns = db.update("YourTableName", newValues, whereClause, whereArgs);
```

The advantage here is that you get correct SQL syntax for free. It also escapes your variables which prevents bad things to happen when you use `"hax ' DROP TABLE '"` as argument for `?`.

The only thing that is still not safe is using `column LIKE ?` with arguments like `"hello%world_"` because `%` (match anything of several chars) and `_` (match any 1 char) are not escaped.
You would need to escape those manually (e.g. place a `!` before each `_` or `%`) and use

```java
String whereClause = "LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'"
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
    likeEscape("bar") 
    // likeEscape could be replaceAll("!", "!!").replaceAll("%", "!%").replaceAll("_", "!_") maybe
}
```

Btw: your single code line should work if you use

```java
db.execSQL( "UPDATE " + Table_name + " SET " + availability + "=0 WHERE " +  product_name + " like 'bar'");
```

Answer (score 1):

SqlLite uses "SQL".  You need a SQL "update"

```
db.execSQL( "update mytable set availability=0 where product_name like '%" + bar + "%'");
```

Here's a good link for SQL "select", "update", "insert" and "delete" (["CRUD"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)) commands:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: don't use `LIKE '%something%'` unless you really want to match several similar items.

Comment: Correct.  Use "=" for an "exact match".  Use "like '%something%'" to do a "wildcard search".  And remember the single quote (') to delimit dates and text strings.